# WCF Wsdl - Get rid of the "tns" xml namespace prefix with my own prefix?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, xml-namespaces, prefix, tns

Is there any way to replace all `tns` prefixes by my own when my `WSDL` is generated?

I know that setting the namespace and name of my `ServiceContract`, `OperationContract`, `DataContract`, etc. makes it so I don't have the ugly http://tempuri.org/ namespace, but how can I change the **prefix**?

Comment: The question: Why do you want that? It has no real meaning. It is just identification and it is acronym from `targetNamespace`

Comment: Are you sure it's not temporary namespace?